# What k-Core is a Vertex In?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

What is the best way to write a quick function which takes in a vertex (of some undirected graph), and **gives the value of the k-Core's in which that vertex is in?**

The obvious modification of `kCoreComponents[Graph,k]` using `Intersection` is either taking ages, since it needs to re-check the core composition for each vertex (I have over 7000), or spends ages "loading" after the script is complete.

Comment: Please add context, and all code and data (perhaps a useful subset) necessary to recreate your problem. Also,`KCoreComponents` with a capital K...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following seems pretty fast:

```
kcores[g_, v_] := With[{max = VertexDegree[g, v]},
    DeleteCases[_->{}] @ Table[
        i -> Select[KCoreComponents[g, i], Not@*FreeQ[v]],
        {i,0,max}
    ]
]
```

Here is @kglr's example:

```
g = Graph[
    {
    1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1<-> 4, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6, 
    6 <-> 7, 6 <-> 8, 6 <-> 9, 7 <-> 8, 7 <-> 9, 8 <-> 9
    }
];

kcores[g, 1]
kcores[g, 5]
kcores[g, 6]
```

> {0 -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}}, 1 -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}}, 
>    2 -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}}, 3 -> {{1, 2, 3, 4}}}
>
> {0 -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}}, 1 -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}}, 
>    2 -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}}}
>
> {0 -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}}, 1 -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}}, 
>    2 -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}}, 3 -> {{6, 7, 8, 9}}}

And a large example:

```
g = RandomGraph[{10000, 50000}];
kcores[g, 1]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.042289, Null}

**Addendum**

Your question asked for the values of the k-cores (note the plural) in which that vertex is in, which is why my function returned a list of all the k-cores that a vertex lives in. Since you accepted the answer returning a single component for a specific value of `k`, here is a variation of my answer to do so:

```
kcore[g_, k_, v_] := SelectFirst[KCoreComponents[g, k], Not @* FreeQ[v]]
```

Let's compare `kcore` with the accepted answer:

```
g = RandomGraph[{10000, 50000}];

r1 = kcore[g, 5, 50]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = kCoreParent[g, 5, 50]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {0.006013, Null}
>
> {0.42559, Null}
>
> True

You did say you were interested in a quick solution.

Comment: Nice, thank you

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[kCoreParent]
kCoreParent[g_, k_, v_] := v /. Dispatch[Flatten[{Thread[# -> #, List, 1] & /@ 
      KCoreComponents[g, k], _ :> {}}]]
```

Example:

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1<-> 4, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6, 
   6 <-> 7, 6 <-> 8, 6 <-> 9, 7 <-> 8, 7 <-> 9, 8 <-> 9},  
  GraphStyle -> "SmallNetwork", ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

```
KCoreComponents[g, 3]
```

> {{6, 7, 8, 9}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}

```
kCoreParent[g, 3, 8]
```

> {6, 7, 8, 9}

```
Grid[Prepend[{#, kCoreParent[g, 3, #]} & /@ {1, 5, 7}, {"  v  ", 
   "kCoreParent[g, 3, v]"}], Dividers -> All, 
 Alignment -> {Center, Center}, ItemStyle -> Directive["Panel", 20]]
```

[image]